# Find the number of integral solutions $(x, y)$ to the equation $xy(x + y + 1) = 2019 ^{2020} + 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the number of integral solutions $(x, y)$ to the following equation:$$xy(x + y + 1) = 2019 ^{2020} + 1$$

I've tried expanding to equate the corresponding terms, but that failed miserably and then I tried to take $\ln$ on both sides and I'm not sure how to continue after that. Can anyone give a little hint on how to start? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Théophile I've tried expanding to equate the corresponding terms.. but that failed miserably and then I tried to take log on both sides and I'm not sure how to continue after that

Comment: Hint: Look at it $\pmod 3$…

Comment: @Macavity  xy(x+y+1)mod3 =1 ?

Comment: Yes. Now what could $x,y$ be? Cant be $0$, you then have only $\pm1$ to try out. I assume you're familiar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: why not any other integer other than +1,-1 and 0?

Comment: notice $3, 9, 27, 81...$ help u to dissolve out $2019^{2020}$ so most of time in such questions u can get rid of it by mod or log so keep this in ur mind it will help u a lot.

Comment: I edited your question to describe your attempt; this is helpful to others in giving relevant advice (and it will make your question less likely to be closed).

Comment: @Théophile thank you

Comment: @dobby:  Because $\bmod 3$ all integers are equivalent to one of  $0,1,-1$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you.. I understood it now

Comment: But isn't it known that xy(x+y+1) mod 3 is 1? so we can rule out -1 and 0... Am I right?

Comment: @dobby You've established that the right-hand side of the equation is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, but that still leaves the left-hand side, which will depend on $x$ and $y$. If, for example, $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then the LHS would be $0$, giving $0\equiv1\pmod3$, a contradiction. The same happens when $y\equiv0\pmod3$. What if $x\equiv1\pmod3$?

Comment: @Théophile yes... I understand it... but wouldn't we get the same result if the RHS in the question is 1,4,7 etc... it's not exclusive only to $2019^{2020} +1$

Comment: Of course, you'll get the same result. So none of them will have integer solutions. It's like asking when is $2n$ an odd number.

Comment: Ah yes... I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Great, then perhaps you could provide a complete answer below so that question maybe resolved and kept as reference for others?

Comment: @Macavity Yes, I've put it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the community for helping me. Here's the solution:

LHS:

$(2019^{2020} + 1)\equiv1\pmod3$

RHS:

(x and y cannot be zero)

if  $x\equiv1\pmod3$ and $y\equiv1\pmod3$,

$xy\equiv1*1\pmod3=1\pmod3$

$x+y\equiv2\pmod3$

$x+y+1\equiv3\pmod3=0\pmod3$

$\Rightarrow$ $xy(x+y+1)\equiv0\pmod3$

LHS $\ne$ RHS

Similarly, LHS and RHS won't be equal even if $x\equiv-1\pmod3$ and $y\equiv-1\pmod3$ and for any other values of x and y.

So there are no integral solutions for the given equation.